# What parameter does wait from parent get when the child executes exit without a parameter

Tags: c, operating-system

The question is of a defaulf exit status .Like if a  shell script fails ,we most of the times get an exit status of 127 .What is the default exit status of a program .

Answer (score 2):

[status](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/)

> Status value returned to the parent
>   process. Generally, a return value of
>   **0** or EXIT_SUCCESS indicates success,
>   and any other value or the constant
>   EXIT_FAILURE is used to indicate an
>   error or some kind of abnormal program
>   termination.

Comment: You are just telling me a very obvious answer .Everybody knows exit_success and exit_failure and the fact that they are defined in stdlib.h And that on calling exit .The child clears up it's u area but leaves the process table entry and gives the parent a SIGCHLD signal .

Comment: Also ,_exit does not close a file descriptor .
Please try to understand what i said .Try not returning a value in a function and check out the exit status , try forcing the compilation errors and/or segmentation faults in the code to check out the exit status .

Comment: This is a question of morris j bach , it has gotta be tougher than ur "EXIT_SUCCESS"

Comment: @richi_18007 : _exit(status) ? I don't know why are talking about file descriptors here? And on compilation error there will be no process?